# 2: No such directory error when running jar from bat file using scheduler

Tags: java, batch-file, jar, windows-task-scheduler

I am trying to schedule up java application using windows scheduler.

I have created bat file where is written: `java -jar C:\....(full path)\myJar.jar`

Java is using data folder, located right next to jar file, during execution. Everyone has access to the data folder so permission is not the issue as far as I understand.

The way I access to the folder in java is by setting path: `"data\\test.csv"`

Please note that bat file is located next to jar file and the data folder.

Interesting is that if I run the bat file manually then everything works fine, when I run it from scheduler, error occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it by adding cd line to bat file. So before execution of jar, directory is changed.

Bat file would look like this:

```
cd C:(full path to directory)
java -jar myJar.jar
pause
```